# RedirectToAction From ActionFilter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How-to access RedirectToAction from a custom ActionFilter ?

```
public class ExceptionHandlingFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Exception != null && !filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
        {
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;

            // HERE : RedirectToAction("ServiceNotFound","Error");

        }
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
    new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary {
        {"controller", "Error"}, {"action", "ServiceNotFound"}
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really. You can either use a RedirectResult or RedirectToRouteResult. If you are looking at redirecting away based on authentication, you should consider that a Controller is an ActionFilter, so you can probably inherit this basic behaviour from a base controller class. Just override the OnActionExecuting method in base class.